# Define the partial derivatives of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, variable-definitions

I have some vector $K = [K_1, K_2,...K_n]$ which is a function of variables $(x,y)$ i.e. $K = K(x,y)$

I want to *symbolically* calculate the partial derivatives e.g. $\partial_x K$, $\partial_x \partial_y K$, $\partial_x^2 K$where I myself *define* the derivatives.

At the moment in my code I am thinking of each of the elements $K$ as a function and I can then define the derivative as e.g.

```
Derivative[1, 0][k1][x_, y_] := k1dx;
```

i.e. this defines $\partial_x K_1$ = `k1dx`. However, I am unsure how to scale this up in a neat, efficient way.

Ideally I want to be able to define the derivatives to be of the form $\partial_a K$ = `[K1da, K2da,...Knda]` and something analogous for the mixed or second derivatives.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Derivative[1, 0][k[i_]][x_, y_] := kdx[i]`?

Comment: Within a `Do` loop you mean?